# javascript's Data.parse() in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, firefox

I have a very simple operation by converting a string in standard format 1985-10-11T12:23:00 (without timezone specified).

Data.parse() in chrome javascript parses it in Date object as is, but in Firefox a correction for time zone applies.

How I can ensure that in both browsers Date.parse produces result without timezone corrections?

Comment: Simply put - you can't. Specify the time zone - times without a time zone are rather meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured that out. Date.Parse accepts information about time zone so to ensure cross-browser compartibility, time zone must be added to the zone-less time stamp.

But most commonly used Z+00 notation does not apply. as per Date Parse doc, one has to specify e.g. UTC timezone as +00:00 right after timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect

```
new Date("1985-10-11T12:23:00").toUTCString()
```